# Letter Spacing in input box in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I want to evenly separate the 6 letters in the input box as below
[image]

instead of just packing together.[image]

I assume that there are **only 6 characters** will be input.

I know that there is a property `letter-spacing` can handle this.

However, as ionic framework is **responsive**, the **width of the input box** varies. Therefore I cannot just hardcode the number to letter-spacing.

Is there any method to handle the letter-spacing problem, no matter in html/css/ts?

Comment: You can use media queries to specify different `letter-spacing` values for different screens or use `vh` unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Yug Kapoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5789305/yug-kapoor) say you can use `letter-spacing` values with `vw` unit

**Code Sample can be like this:**

```css
.div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  width: 40%;
  letter-spacing: calc(6vw - 12px);
  padding-left: calc(6vw - 12px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <input type="text" class="input" value="123456" />
</div>
```

And, you can look this links;

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

[viewport percentage](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)